# Path planning with adaptive Monte Carlo Localization ( AMCL )

Tags: ros, navigation, path, amcl, pathplanning

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

The localisation for my mobile robot works with the AMCL package. Apparently you can also implement path planning with this package. But I don't find anything about this, how does this work?

This is my current launch file for the localisation:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<launch>

<!-- load map -->
<arg name="map_file" default="$(find mastering_ros_demo_pkg)/trappenhaliteratie20.yaml"/>

<node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(arg map_file)" />


    <!-- start hokuyo_node -->
<node name="hokuyo_node" pkg="hokuyo_node" type="hokuyo_node" output="screen"/>

  <arg name="tf_map_scanmatch_transform_frame_name" default="scanmatcher_frame"/>
  <arg name="base_frame" default="base_footprint"/>
  <arg name="odom_frame" default="nav"/>
  <arg name="pub_map_odom_transform" default="true"/>
  <arg name="scan_subscriber_queue_size" default="5"/>
  <arg name="scan_topic" default="scan"/>
  <arg name="map_size" default="2048"/>

    <!-- start odometry_node -->
<node name="odometry" pkg="mastering_ros_demo_pkg" type="odometry" output="screen"/>

    <!-- tf transform -->
 <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="map_nav_broadcaster" args="-0.45 0 0 3.1765 0 3.1415 /base_link /laser 100"/>

    <!-- Generate robot model -->
 <param name="robot_description" command="cat $(find mastering_ros_demo_pkg)/urdf/rolstoel.urdf" /> 



  
<node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz"/>

<node pkg="amcl" type="amcl" name="amcl" output="screen">
  <!-- Publish scans from best pose at a max of 10 Hz -->
  <param name="odom_model_type" value="diff"/>
  <param name="odom_alpha5" value="0.1"/>
  <param name="transform_tolerance" value="0.2" />
  <param name="gui_publish_rate" value="10.0"/>
  <param name="laser_max_beams" value="30"/>
  <param name="min_particles" value="500"/>
  <param name="max_particles" value="5000"/>
  <param name="kld_err" value="0.05"/>
  <param name="kld_z" value="0.99"/>
  <param name="odom_alpha1" value="0.2"/>
  <param name="odom_alpha2" value="0.2"/>
  <!-- translation std dev, m -->
  <param name="odom_alpha3" value="0.8"/>
  <param name="odom_alpha4" value="0.2"/>
  <param name="laser_z_hit" value="0.5"/>
  <param name="laser_z_short" value="0.05"/>
  <param name="laser_z_max" value="0.05"/>
  <param name="laser_z_rand" value="0.5"/>
  <param name="laser_sigma_hit" value="0.2"/>
  <param name="laser_lambda_short" value="0.1"/>
  <param name="laser_lambda_short" value="0.1"/>
  <param name="laser_model_type" value="likelihood_field"/>
  <!-- <param name="laser_model_type" value="beam"/> -->
  <param name="laser_likelihood_max_dist" value="2.0"/>
  <param name="update_min_d" value="0.2"/>
  <param name="update_min_a" value="0.5"/>
  <param name="odom_frame_id" value="odom"/>
  <param name="resample_interval" value="1"/>
  <param name="transform_tolerance" value="0.1"/>
  <param name="recovery_alpha_slow" value="0.0"/>
  <param name="recovery_alpha_fast" value="0.0"/>
</node>




</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234234/path-planning-with-adaptive-monte-carlo--localization--(-amcl-)/) by [Bert](https://answers.ros.org/users/26233/bert/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2016-05-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AMCL localizes your robot. That localization is then fed into a planner (like [move_base](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base)) for navigation. See the [navigation stack](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation) and the [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/indigo/Setup%20the%20Navigation%20Stack%20for%20TurtleBot) for more help.

---

Originally posted by [curranw](https://answers.ros.org/users/17736/curranw/) with karma: 211 on 2016-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0